# Rust is claiming that this pattern case is unreachable, why?

Tags: rust, union

Given this code

```
union IntOrFloat {
    i: i32,
    f: f32,
}

fn process_value(iof: IntOrFloat) {
    unsafe {
        match iof {
            IntOrFloat { i: 42 } => {
                println!("meaning of life value");
            }
            IntOrFloat { i } => {
                println!("integer with value {}", i);
            }
            IntOrFloat { f } => {
                println!("f32 = {}", f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Rust is giving me the following warning:

```
warning: unreachable pattern
   --> src\main.rs:445:13
    |
445 |             IntOrFloat { f } => {
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: #[warn(unreachable_patterns)] on by default
```

Why am I getting this? Clearly the `i` case takes an `i32`, and the `f` case takes an `f32` and both are possible.

Update: CLion agrees with me

[image: CLion inference of union cases]

Comment: *"Clearly the i case takes an i32, and the f case takes an f32"* Why do you think so? How should the compiler deduce those two conditions in your opinion? By looking at the variable name?

Comment: @hellow yes, absolutely, I've added a CLion screenshot above

Comment: Please look at the suggested duplicate. I think it clearly solves your issue. Please note, that CLion is third party code and does not use the rust compiler AFAIK.

Comment: Do you want to use `enum` ? please avoid screenshot

Comment: @Stargateur I think a screenshot is okay-ish here to debate (it proves his point why he thinks it should work). Although I wish it wouldn't be that big ^^

Answer (score 1):

from [rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/unions.html):

> Another way to access union fields is to use pattern matching. Pattern matching on union fields uses the same syntax as struct patterns, except that the pattern must specify exactly one field

so no, union can't be matched like this. External documentation (or sources) is the only way to determine which union field should be used. That's why it is marked as unsafe

Comment: How does your answer differ from the suggested duplicate? Please avoid giving redundant information.